# How to choose only locations that are close to travelers using android

Tags: java, android, gps, android-gps

I am new to  andoid programming .I have been provided with a challenge regarding the cab share which has to happen on the go or at realtime.

> Challenge:

Assume if multiple users opted for a share.If user1 chooses one location and user2 chooses location which is very far from user1. Cab driver has to do a round circle to cover both the destinations.

> Requirement:

Is there any API which helps to get the locations that
are close to travelers can only be chosen .

> Eg : If user1 is travelling to place1 and user2 is travelling to
>   place2 wherein place1 and place2 comes under one single stretch  so
>   that driver can cover both the location in one single ride.

Currently even Ola,Uber are also facing the same challenges I bileave.

I tried with Google Maps Directions API. Directions between multiple locationsfrom  https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/?csw=1
api to get nearby locations but how to match with realtime is what I need 
TIA 
Pradeep

Comment: What have you tried? No one is going to do the work for you.

Comment: dude, I would downvote for incorrect question, I should ask, what u have done so far?

Comment: can you show smth

Comment: see this example http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-and-google-map-android-api-v2/

Comment: @non destructive.I have updated the question.One more thing I am not asking for entire code buddy instead any api's which I can make use of to get realtime data is what I am asking.

Comment: @SA.I updated my question.

Comment: @Saurabh thanks .I will hae a look at it .